# An automatic way to create gameobjects in Unity?

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, gameobject

Basically is there an actually time saving way to creat a function that lets you create a GameObject specified by the function's parameter(s)?

like:

```
public void thing_maker(string gameobject_name, string sprite_name, string rg_body_name)
```

Comment: Yup, you can either call `new GameObject()` (which will create a blank, empty GameObject) to which you might add components to (via `AddComponent<ComponentType>()`) or call [`UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(gameObjectToCopy)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) which will create a copy. You can also instantiate prefabs at runtime. Some detailed information here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html

Comment: Great, but can you specify the `GameObject()`'s name from an argument `thing_maker()`?  Like calling `thing_maker(go_player, sprt_player, rgdbdy_player)` Will create a gameobject with the name go_player, a sprite called sprt_player, etc.

Comment: Sure, just check [the docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-ctor.html). You have to add the components yourself or instantiate a prefab, but what's stopping you from trying to implement this method?

Answer (score 1):

this example should do what you need.
it requires that you have a folder named **Resources** and that the sprite you want to load will be inside that folder.

another option is doing `GameObject go = Instantite(SomePrefabName) as GameObject` insted of `new GameObject()`, in case you have a prefab which is ready and you only want to maybe change some of its components' values.

Good luck.

```
public GameObject thing_maker(string gameobject_name, string sprite_name, string rg_body_name)
{
    GameObject go = new GameObject(gameobject_name);
    SpriteRenderer sr = go.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    sr.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(sprite_name);
    Rigidbody rb = go.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();

    /* now if you want to change values of the components you can just do it
       by accesing them directly. for instance: rb.isKinematic = true; will
       change the isKinematic value of this rigidbody to true. */

    return go;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you could try something like this:

```
public void ThingMaker(string gameobject_name, Sprite spriteToDraw) {
    GameObject newObj;
    newObj= new GameObject(gameobject_name);
    newObj.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); 
    newObj.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    newObj.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = spriteToDraw;
}
```